# How to fetch songart (AlbumArt) from the internal and external storage of device?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-contentresolver

I am trying to make a music player app.

I want a listview with an image of the song and the songtitle and artist name.

Something like this.

[image]

I have figured out the songName and songTitle using Content Resolver but I don't know how to display the respective art of that song.

Here is my ListSong.java which is used to fetch songs from the device.

```
public class ListSong extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listsongs, container, false);

        songView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.songsList);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        getSongList();

        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getActivity(), songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

        return rootView;

    }

    public void getSongList(){
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                    (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

}
```

An here is my SongInfo(Song.java) class

```
public class Song {

    private long id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;

    public Song(long songID, String songTitle, String songArtist) {
        this.id = songID;
        this.title = songTitle;
        this.artist = songArtist;
    }

    public long getID(){return id;}
    public String getTitle(){return title;}
    public String getArtist(){return artist;}

}
```

I just want to if there is any way to fetch respective songart to their songs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code to get Song Art:

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
int albumIDColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
long thisAlbumID = musicCursor.getLong(albumIDColumn);
Cursor cursor = musicResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                        MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                        new String[]{String.valueOf(thisAlbumID)},
                        null);          
String imagePath = "";
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART));
}
```

Comment: Should I also edit the Song Class because it is storing the song Info.

Comment: yes you need to change your bean class as one new parameter added.

Comment: Hey Sorry to bother, but I am a beginner in this things, can you just fully write the code for the Content Resolver and the Song class as I have written in my question, If you have time.

Comment: @Aditya Verma you should try it out yourself and post here if you stuck somewhere. This is what this community is meant for...

Comment: After implementing your answer to my code. It doesn't seem to work. The app keeps crashing. Can you take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811103/i-want-to-get-the-album-art-from-the-external-storage-of-the-device-and-display